# Auth::user() returns NULL after redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to log-in  to my Laravel application, and I face some weird issue that I didn't seem to know why.

I have a function:

```
public function postLogin(){

    $input = array(
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    );

    $rules = array(
        'username'  => 'Required',
        'password'  => 'Required'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if ($validator->passes()){

        // Try to log the user in.
        if (Auth::attempt($input)){
            $input['status'] = 1;


            //return Auth::user();
            return Redirect::to('/dashboard')->with('success', 'You have logged in successfully');
        }
        else{

            return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors(array('password' => 'Password invalid'))->withInput(Input::except('password'));
        }
    }

    return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors($validator)->withInput(Input::except('password'));
}
```

When I did `return Auth::user();` I got my user printing out.

```
{"id":18,"username":"bheng","email":"benlong@biossusa.com","first_name":"benlong","last_name":"Heng","updated_at":"2016-10-29 15:05:36","created_at":"2014-06-27 19:58:53","status":1,"timezone":"US\/Eastern","lock_version":10,"remember_token":"s2ogIchC7KIfduiFslKwUwW2IYMgcFaDESSUd0UMcPwBYRIxZmpRbqkKfBWt"}
```

Then, I place line in stead

```
return Redirect::to('/dashboard')->with('success', 'You have logged in successfully');
```

I got redirect to the `/dashboard` page, and `dashboard.blade.php` got loaded with this error

> Trying to get property of non-object

Then, I check my `Auth::user()` while in my `dashboard.blade.php`

It returns `NULL`.

Why is it suddenly it returning `null` ?

What should I check ? Session / Auth / Apache / Laravel ?

Comment: It seems a session problem. Are you using a separate front-end or blade views?

Comment: I am using blade views.  How do I check or test my sessions ?

Comment: Which Laravel 4.xxx version do you have?

Comment: Is the storage directory writeable?

Comment: are you on a load balanced server where the session is being stored in a text file on the other box?

Answer (score -2):

u can use Auth::user()->username to get Username value of your current user.

Comment: i say u can't get value of Auth::user() on your view, is an objet. u just can access to all attributs, and see if it's set.

Comment: @AxelBruneaux you still did not understand the question: Auth:user() returns **null** wherever is called. You can use Auth::user() from a view.